# MessagingException thrown on some machines, but on others it works fine

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to write a method that sends an email based on parameters, and it works completely on CentOS and OSX. However, the method doesn't work properly on Windows (even when recompiled on Windows) as well as some other Linux OS's - it throws a MessagingException. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this to work on Windows? Thanks!

```
private static void sendEmail(String towhom, String subject, String body) {
  String host = "smtp.gmail.com", from = "myemail", pass = "mypassword";
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  try {
     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
     props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
     props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
     props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
     props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
     props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(towhom);

     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
     message.setSubject(subject);
     message.setText(body);

     Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
     transport.connect(host, from, pass);
     transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
     transport.close();
  }
  catch(AddressException e) {
     System.out.println("Invalid Email Address.");
  }
  catch(MessagingException e) {
     System.out.print("\nInvalid Email Address, please reenter it: ");
     sendEmail(scan.nextLine(), subject, body);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace? Also, could you do `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587` from you linux terminal?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` in the `MessagingException` catch block.

Comment: It was too long to just paste: http://pastebin.com/02xP4171

Comment: Telnetted from linux terminal:

Trying 173.194.77.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com (173.194.77.109).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP tv3sm1600653obb.8 - gsmtp

Comment: Your code works fine in my Linux machine

Comment: Yeah it works fine from my Linux machine too, just not my Windows nor my friend's Linux machine. My friend and I are running different versions of Java, though. He's running 1.6.0_43 and I'm running 1.6.0_24. On Windows I'm running 1.7.0_09. How about you?

Comment: Your code is fine. It looks like a machine specific problem. Can you disable the firewall on the machine that is giving this exception?

Comment: I get the same error with the firewall disabled

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the specific network environment of the poster, this is too localized and only the poster can solve this problem which is unrelated to what is being asked in this question.

Comment: Didn't know it was a machine-specific question at first. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So yes Avast Antivirus was causing the exception to be thrown when I was trying to send the mail. If anyone else has this problem who finds this page:

Open up Avast and click on the Security tab. Then click on the AntiVirus tab on the left. Under that, click Mail Shield and go to the settings. Untick "Scan outbound mail (SMTP)" and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code. It looks good.

According to the [JavaMail FAQ's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert). Following could be the problem -

- There's a firewall or anti-virus program intercepting your request.
- There's something wrong in your JDK installation preventing it from finding the certificates for the trusted certificate authorities.
- You're running in an application server that has overridden the JDK's list of trusted certificate authorities.

If disabling your firewall and/or anti-virus does not solve the problem then you can try and reinstall the JDK and test.

Comment: I am sure the stack trace will tell him what to look for.

Comment: Thank you! It turned out to be avast! blocking it rather than Windows Firewall. Disabling avast! allows it to run without error.